# CSS3 Animation multiple hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have 2 divs. When I hover the mouse over one div it expands changing the height. I want to make it display a text with fade in effect somewhere in the screen when I hover the mouse over that div and finally when I click on the div, I want to display another div or text somewhere in the screen again. This is the code I've created so far.

```
<style>
        #container
    {
        width:212px;
        position:fixed;
        left:42.5%;
        top:21.7%;
        border: 0px solid red;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #first
    {
        background-color:#fff;
        width:67px;
        height:212px;
        -webkit-transition:all 1s, -webkit-transform 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
        -moz-transition:all 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
        -ms-transition:all 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
        -o-transition:all 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
        transition:all 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
        transition:all 1s, transform 1s;    
        float:left;
    }

    #first:hover
    {
        height:354px;

    }


    #second
    {
        background-color:#fff;
        width:45px;
        height:212px;
        -webkit-transition:all 1s, -webkit-transform 1s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
        -moz-transition:all 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
        -ms-transition:all 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
        -o-transition:all 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
        transition:all 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
        transition:all 1s, transform 1s;
        float:left;
        margin-left:15px;
    }

    #second:hover
    {
        height:354px;
    }

</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

Any ides ?  :/

Comment: which function are looking for exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/vLz3c/1/

I've created a pargraph inside the `#second` element, and made that show up while you hover the `#second` element.

It also increases the height.

EDIT:

http://jsfiddle.net/vLz3c/2/

Now i have used the jQuery function `fadeIn` when hovering the `#second` box.

EDIT 2:

http://jsfiddle.net/vLz3c/3/

Now the `paragraph` also fades out, when you move your mouse away from the `#second` box

EDIT: 3

As promised, when you click the `#second` element, the `#third` element fades in.

http://jsfiddle.net/vLz3c/4/

Comment: My mistake I forgot to mention that I want the text appears with fade in effect when I hover over the div

Comment: ook this is just PERFECT I appreciate your help :D :D have you any idea how can I make the div clickable so it can appear a new div with text or a form ?

Comment: I do, ill do it tonight. But if this resolved your problem, accept my answer, so other people know this issue have been fixed. But then ill update this answer in a few hours.

Comment: @ArisHorizon Updated the thread, now when you click the `#second` element, the `#third` element fades in.

Comment: So if I add this 

$('#first').click(function () {
    $('#third').fadeOut(2000);
}); 

when I click the first the third will disappear?

Comment: @ArisHorizon exactly :)

Comment: I copied the code to my file and I added the jQuery file but still doesn't work 

<script src="js/jquery-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#second').hover(function () {
    $('p').fadeIn(1000);
}, function () {
    $('p').fadeOut(2000);
});

$('#second').click(function () {
    $('#third').fadeIn(2000);
});
</script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second">
        <p>Paragraph!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="third">
        <p>A new paragraph!</p>
    </div>
</div>
 did I miss something ? :/

Comment: Can you please use code tags? And what doesnt work? @ArisHorizon

Comment: oh sorry ! and it's ook It is working perfect I found what was wrong :D